# Python launching VLC with arguments

Tags: python-3.x, vlc

I am having trouble launching VLC with arguments from python script. I am using python 3.9.6 on Win10 21H1 build 1081.

Running this command works from cmd.exe which I have translated in the python code.

```
"C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe" -I dummy 1.m4a --sout="#transcode{vcodec=none,acodec=mp3,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=8000,scodec=none}:std{access=file{no-overwrite},mux=mp3,dst=1.mp3}" vlc://quit
```

I tried two methods. In method 1 I send arguments separately as below.

```
import subprocess as objSubProcess
strFileName = "1.m4a"
strNewFileName = "1.mp3"
g_strVLCPath = "C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe"

strCmd = []
strCmd.append(g_strVLCPath)
strLine = "-I dummy " + strFileName
strCmd.append(strLine)
strLine = "--sout=\"#transcode{vcodec=none,acodec=mp3,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=8000,scodec=none}:std{access=file{no-overwrite},mux=mp3,dst="
strLine = strLine + strNewFileName + "}\""
strCmd.append(strLine)
strCmd.append("vlc://quit")

# Run VLC
objSubProcess.run(strCmd)
```

This code just returns immediately. My guess is VLC launches and exits immediately.

In method 2 I combined all arguments into one as below.

```
import subprocess as objSubProcess
strFileName = "1.m4a"
strNewFileName = "1.mp3"
g_strVLCPath = "C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe"

strCmd = []
strCmd.append(g_strVLCPath)

strLine = "-I dummy " + "\"" + strFileName + "\" "
strLine = strLine + "--sout=\"#transcode{vcodec=none,acodec=mp3,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=8000,scodec=none}:std{access=file{no-overwrite},mux=mp3,dst="
strLine = strLine + strNewFileName + "}\"" + " vlc://quit"
strCmd.append(strLine)

# Run VLC
objSubProcess.run(strCmd)
```

Here VLC launches (as I can see in the task manager) but my code hangs and does not return even after a long time.

In both the cases I don't get the .mp3 that I desire.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please don't add "solved" to your question title. Instead, mark one of the answers as accepted, or if you prefer, post a new answer of your own and mark that as accepted. See further [help.](/help/someone-annswers)

Comment: Since it required 8 hours to accept my own solution I did not want people to keep looking at this during this time. Hence I added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. I passed a single string with all arguments as a simple string instead of an array. Here is the code that worked for me.

```
import subprocess as objSubProcess
strFileName = "1.m4a"
strNewFileName = "1.mp3"
g_strVLCPath = "C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe"

strLine = "\"" + g_strVLCPath + "\" -I dummy " + strFileName
strLine = strLine + " --sout=\"#transcode{vcodec=none,acodec=mp3,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=8000,scodec=none}:std{access=file{no-overwrite},mux=mp3,dst="
strLine = strLine + strNewFileName + "}\""
strLine = strLine + " vlc://quit"

# Run VLC
objSubProcess.run(strLine)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to pass multiple arguments in a list, you have to separate all of them:

```
strFileName = "1.m4a"
strNewFileName = "1.mp3"
g_strVLCPath = "C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe"

strCmd = [
    g_strVLCPath,
    "-I",
    "dummy",
    strFileName,
    '--sout="#transcode{vcodec=none,acodec=mp3,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=8000,scodec=none}:std{access=file{no-overwrite},mux=mp3,dst=' + strNewFileName + '}"',
     "vlc://quit"
]

# Run VLC
objSubProcess.run(strCmd)
```

On Windows, `shell=True` is always implied because of how `cmd.exe` works. That means that python will assemble your arguments into a single command line and escape or quote things like spaces. This is critical towards understanding why both of your approaches did not work. If you want to pass in a single string you can do that on Windows directly, though I'd still recommend adding `shell=True` to make your intention clear:

```
strFileName = "1.m4a"
strNewFileName = "1.mp3"
g_strVLCPath = "C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe"

strCmd = f'{g_strVLCPath} -I dummy {strFileName} --sout="#transcode{{vcodec=none,acodec=mp3,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=8000,scodec=none}}:std{{access=file{{no-overwrite}},mux=mp3,dst={strNewFileName}}} vlc://quit'

# Run VLC
objSubProcess.run(strCmd, shell=True)
```

In your first attempt, you have a single list element containing `"-I dummy 1.m4a"`. When you pass that to the shell, it's going to get turned into that string *including* the quotes, because you specified it as a single argument containing spaces, instead of three separate arguments.

In your second attempt, you concatenated the arguments more-or-less correctly, but didn't add the program name to the string. Since you're passing in a list, python will surround everything with double quotes and escape all the quotes inside.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I will keep these in mind.

Comment: Ok was not aware of that. I did it now.

Answer (score 0):

In first use second argument of subprocess.run() method for passing arguments for vlc [Subprocess management](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).

Two arguments of subprocess.run() method is usefull:

1. If capture_output is true, stdout and stderr will be captured.
   Usefull for troubleshooting.
2. The timeout argument. If the timeout
   expires, the child process will be killed and waited for.

Comment: Passing arguments to VLC as second argument is what I have done in method 2. That also did not work.